Common Lisp - Any ideas on how to write a "with-methods" macro similar to "with-slots"?
So my idea is to reduce the amount of calls to an object instance, when it is clearly the only one in scope.
Here's a code example:
(defun read-plist (plist)
    (let ((plist-reader (make-instance 'plist-reader))
        (loop for (indicator value) in plist
            do (read-indicator plist-reader indicator)
            do (read-value plist-readere value))
        plist-reader)) 

And here is what I want it to look like:
(defun read-plist (plist)
    (let ((plist-reader (make-instance 'plist-reader))
        (with-methods (read-indicator (rv read-value)
                plist-reader)
            (loop for (indicator value) in plist
                do (read-indicator indicator)
                do (rv value)))
        plist-reader))

I suppose it's not really the best example since it makes the code look even more complicated. But I can imagine a case where it would shave off a good bit of complexity. Maybe I'm looking in a totally wrong direction, but my original idea is to reduce the use of names, when scope is clearly local. Would it simply be a better practice to have a small package of its own, where functions replace the need to bind methods to a specific object? I suppose there isn't one true answer, but anyways.. What are your takes on the macro? :D
I tried looking in the direction of defining the macro this way:
(defmacro with-methods (methods class-instance &rest code) 
    ...) 

But it seems I would need to look through all the rest code, figure find all the occurences of the given methods and modify them as lists. It raises a dilema of performance issues to me. Maybe there's a classical approach to this that I have missed? From a standpoint of a Common Lisp beginner, I find documentation unsearchable and only readable after ChatGPT's take on it tbh.

Is pr-instance supposed to be plist-reader?

WITH-SLOTS is possible because there's a standard SLOT-VALUE function that it can expand all the slot references into. But the way methods are called is peculiar to each method -- the instance isn't always the same place in the argument list.

@Shawn Yes, sure. Edited the code. Thank you.

The plist-reader parameter should not be in the same list as the list of methods. It should probably be something like (with-method plist-reader (read-indicator (rv read-value)) body)

if you're willing to limit it to functions that take the instance as the first argument, it should be simple for with-methods to expand into flet. You don't need to look through the code at all.

(flet ((read-indicator (&rest args) (apply #'read-indicator plist-reader args))) .,body)

@Barmar I understand that argument order is important, but I see no other way, than pusing the responsibility on the programmer. As for SLOT-VALUE, can you give me a simple example on how it can be done, given that the first argument to the bound method is always the class instance? I would assume the use of lambda function in place of initform, but I still struggle to see how it's going to be implemented.

I just showed you what it should expand into.

For rv it expands into (flet ((rv (&rest args) (apply #'read-value plist-reader args))) .,body)

@Barmar took me too long to type that in :D Thank you, it does answer my question.

@Barmar I suppose I do have one more question. What's the purpose of ., before body? I've never seen such notation used anywhere, nor can I find it ever being mentioned, but in Sceme docs where it appeared vaguely with no explaination.

It's similar to ,@body. They splice the body into the list.

looks like a great way to obfuscate your code. Nobody will understand what the undocumented macro with unclear naming&syntax will do.

"I find documentation unsearchable and only readable after ChatGPT's take on it tbh." ChatGPT isn't an authority on anything, and the entire point of reading documentation is to read an authoritative source. Please don't make ChatGPT your go-to source for understanding; rather learn to read the real documentation; this is a skill that takes time to develop, but it's worth it. You can bring questions about the meaning of the documentation here or to other CL communities when you need help with that. For searchability, you can find PDFs of the HyperSpec and CLTL2 that are easier to search.

@adabsurdum Nah, surely I try my best at reading it myself. I simply find myself lacking, well, poetry in it. AI adds some lyrics and accentuation to an otherwise very technical manner of speech, that's all. There's no way I would rely on it not hallucinating important connections, but it still makes it much more like reading a book.

I'm not at all sure that doing this is something that's desirable at all.  However, if it is there are two obvious problems:

methods can specialise on any positional argument (or all of them), not just the first;
methods can have completely general arglists including keyword arguments.

These problems, between them, make the problem extremely hard to solve in any general way.
The first one can be avoided by simply insisting that the additional argument you're going to insert is the first.  That leaves the second.  The second can be avoided by insisting that there are no non-simple argument lists, and in particular no lambda-list keywords in the argument list.  These simplifications make the resulting simpler version of the problem tractable.  It's still not clear to me that it's desirable.
The following macro specifies method shorthands as (shorthand method/args) where method/args is either a method name or a cons of (method-name . extra-args).  It avoids using apply, inlines the local functions and evaluates the object form only once.
(defmacro with-method-shorthands ((&rest method-specifiers) object &body forms)
  ;; All methods take the object as their first argument.  There can
  ;; be no non-simple arglists for method shorthands.
  (let ((<object> (make-symbol "<OBJECT>")))
    `(let ((,<object> ,object))         ;with-names
       (flet ,(mapcar (lambda (method-specifier)
                        (destructuring-bind (name method/args) method-specifier
                          (multiple-value-bind (method additional-args)
                              (etypecase method/args
                                (symbol
                                 (values method/args '()))
                                (cons
                                 (values (first method/args) (rest method/args))))
                            (unless (null (intersection additional-args lambda-list-keywords))
                              (error "Can't parse complicated arglist"))
                            `(,name (,@additional-args)
                               (,method ,<object> ,@additional-args)))))
                      method-specifiers)
         (declare (inline ,@(mapcar #'first method-specifiers)))
         ,@forms))))

Now
(with-method-shorthands ((foo (bar a)) (bine bone)) (thing-returning-object)
  (foo x))
 -> (let ((#:<object> (thing-returning-object)))
      (flet ((foo (a) (bar #:<object> a)) (bine () (bone #:<object>)))
        (declare (inline foo bine))
        (foo x)))

Where all the symbols that look the same are the same.  Note this is not even slightly going to work on setf methods, which very often specialise on their second argument:
(defmethod (setf thing) (new (object my-class))
  ...)


For fun, here is a more complicated version of the above macro which allows you to specify where you want the object to be spliced in the arguments:
(defmacro with-method-shorthands ((&rest method-specifiers) object &body forms)
  (let ((<object> (make-symbol "<OBJECT>")))
    `(let ((,<object> ,object))         ;with-names
       (flet ,(mapcar (lambda (method-specifier)
                        (destructuring-bind (name method/args) method-specifier
                          (multiple-value-bind (method pre-args post-args)
                              (etypecase method/args
                                (symbol
                                 (values method/args '() '()))
                                (cons
                                 (destructuring-bind (method &rest options) method/args
                                   (unless (null (intersection options lambda-list-keywords))
                                     (error "complicated arglist"))
                                   (cond
                                    ((some #'keywordp options)
                                     (destructuring-bind (&key (pre '()) (post '())) options
                                       (values method pre post)))
                                    ((every #'symbolp options)
                                     (values method '() options))
                                    (t
                                     (error "bogus arglist (non-symbols)"))))))
                            `(,name ,(append pre-args post-args)
                               (,method ,@pre-args ,<object> ,@post-args)))))
                      method-specifiers)
         (declare (inline ,@(mapcar #'first method-specifiers)))
         ,@forms))))

With this version
(with-method-shorthands ((a (a :pre (x y) :post (z)))
                         (b (b p q))
                         (c c))
                        (make-thing)
  (a b c d))
 -> (let ((#:<object> (make-thing)))
      (flet ((a (x y z)
               (a x y #:<object> z))
             (b (p q)
               (b #:<object> p q))
             (c ()
               (c #:<object>)))
        (declare (inline a b c))
        (a b c d)))


with-accessors is similar to with-slots, but accessors are methods. This way, you minimize the writing of method calls. Is this what you want to achieve?

https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html#a-function-that-always-works-slot-value
https://cl-community-spec.github.io/pages/with_002daccessors.html

(with-accessors ((name        name)
                  ^^variable  ^^accessor
                 (lisper lisper))
            p1
          (format t "name: ~a, lisper: ~a" name lisper))

Any call to "name" will be expanded to a call to the accessor method. Instead of say (setf (name person) "you") (a normal accessor use) you can write (setf name "you") inside the "with-accessors".

As @Barmar explained in the comments, with-methods can expand into flet:
(defmacro with-methods (methods class-instance &rest body) 
  "Reduces calls to class methods down to their names and rest parameters, 
given that the first argument to every method is class instance.
Acts similarly to 'with-slots'.
'methods' argument is a list of method names, that may contain
sublists with short names like so: 
(actual-method-name-1 (mn-2 actual-method-name-2)"

  `(flet ,(loop for method-name in methods
                if (listp method-name)
                  collect `(,(first method-name) (&rest args)
                             (apply #',(second method-name) ,class-instance args))
                else
                  collect `(,method-name (&rest args)
                             (apply #',method-name ,class-instance args)))
     ,@body))

Where loop part takes care of method names passed to the macro in the following manner:
(method-name-1 (m-name-2 method-name-2))
I tested the code and it works like a charm. Forgive this multiple unquoting, I hope it's readable :D

This answer multiply-evaluates the class instance.
